# How to run MATLAB(64bit) on Ubuntu 12.04(32bit)

Tags: 12.04, installation, matlab

I've Ubuntu 12.04 (32bit) And Windows 7 (64bit).
I've installed "MATLAB-R2011b" on Windows 7.
How can i run that on Ubuntu without using WINE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run Windows applications on Ubuntu without using WINE. You can also not run 64-bit applications on a 32-bit system.

Your options are to reboot to Windows to run the application, or upgrade to 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 and use WINE, or set up a VM image to run your existing copy of Windows while in Ubuntu, and run MatLab in a VM.

Comment: Is there any way to install MATLAB on ubuntu ?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB